# how to access my ubuntu files after booting with a live usb

Tags: boot, usb

I have been running ubuntu 16.04.3 on a macbook (single boot) for sometime.
Since yesterday, the laptop does not boot. 
Ι have some small .mus files saved on the desktop that I need to recover. 
Can i somehow access them if I boot from a 'live usb' ? 
And how can i save them to the usb and/or upload them on my 'cloud' drive?

Thanks a lot,

please let me know if i should provide more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this has been asked before, as a live-usb is a perfect way to do this.

But anyways.

Once you make the live-usb, you should be able to boot up the system by going to boot options during the machine-start up. (Usually entered by striking ESC, F11 or F12 during the boot up process) and boot from USB. Then you just go to My Computer or whatever and act as if you're opening up a USB stick, just clicking on the hard drive, and it should let you enter into the hard drive. From there, just go to the Users folder, or whatever is similar, and take out the files you need and place them wherever you like.

If you do not have persistence enabled on your live-usb, *these files will not be saved across boots* (they will disappear after shutting down the system). Look into persistence, or find yourself another memory device before booting up!

Comment: i found a way around this b4 reading your answer, still i upvoted because you clarify the 'saving to usb part' thanks a lot!!! can you explain a bit more about persistence?

Comment: Of course. There's thousands of documentation. Basically you need to create a partition in the USB using MiniPartitionTool or something, make it ext4, and name it persistence. Then you set that partition as persistence. What happens is that a normal live-usb usually won't save changes when you shut down the system. So you store the changes and the user profile on this partition. Go look it up somewhere, the internet explains it better. :D

Answer (score 0):

1. plug in the live usb. reboot holding down the 'cmd' key on the macbook
2. when on the grub menu choose the first option: 'try ubuntu without   installing'
3. once the system has booted from the live usb, open a terminal and type: 'sudo nautilus'
4. with root privileges using gui now go to the home folder then -in my case- the 's' folder and from there to 'desktop'. the files i was looking for can be uploaded to a cloud storage using the default browser!

hope it's helpful for other people too!